# UITableviewCell accessoryView can't be changed

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uiaccessoryview

I need to change the accessoryView to proper UIImageView

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     var cell = tableView .dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ActivitySectionCell") as! ActivitySectionCell
     var imageNameOfAccessory = expandedSections.containsIndex(indexPath.section) ? "collapse" : "edit"
     cell.accessoryView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: imageNameOfAccessory))
     return cell
}


func tableView(tableViewMethod: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            tableViewMethod.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

               var cell = tableView(self.tableViewMain, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath) as! ActivitySectionCell
               if currentlyExpanded {
                    var imageNameOfAccessory = !currentlyExpanded ? "collapse" : "edit"
                    cell.accessoryView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: imageNameOfAccessory))
                }
                else {
                    var imageNameOfAccessory = !currentlyExpanded ? "collapse" : "edit"
                    cell.accessoryView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: imageNameOfAccessory))
                }


    }
```

I checked in debug, sometimes I set "collapse" image, sometimes "edit" image, but after that I always see "edit" image in the cell.

So when I set accessoryView at the very beginning , I can't change it after that (actually I can change the view pointer, but after that on the screen I don't see any changes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was in the row:

```
var cell = tableView(self.tableViewMain, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath) as! ActivitySectionCell
```

I had to change it to :

```
var cell = tableViewMain.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ActivitySectionCell
```

Because otherwise I will change not the current cell, but other returning cell

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have to do the `if currentlyExpanded {` check in `cellForRowAtIndex` and just call `self.tableView.reloadData` in the `didSelectRowAtIndex`.

Comment: yes, it helps, but it's blinking , why can't I use it in didSelectRowAtIndex?